# Check that a data file contains the expected number of rows and columns of integers

Tags: java, validation, file, csv

This is a class I wrote check to check the format of .dat files.  My code makes sure that the content of the files satisfies the conditions.

A file can be deemed invalid if:

- The file can't be found.
- The file contains data in the wrong format.
- The values don't match the expected data types.
- There are fewer rows and/or columns of data than specified.
- There are more rows and/or columns of data than specified.

e.g.

```
 3 3
 1 4 5
 7 5 3
 2 9 0
```

What can I do to make my code more efficient?

```
// Should we check to see if numbers are seperated by more than one space?


  public class FormatChecker {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Checks to make sure at least one file has been provided via command line
            if (args.length > 0) {
                for (String fileName : args) {
                    File file = new File(fileName);
                    // Checks to make sure file is a file and that the file exists
                    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
                        // Catches if file still exists and is a file
                        try {
                            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
                            String trueRowCol = fileScan.nextLine().trim();
                            String[] dimToken = trueRowCol.split("\\s+");
                            String trueRowStr = dimToken[0];
                            String trueColStr = dimToken[1];
                            // Checks to make sure there is not an extra integer on the first line
                            if (dimToken.length > 2) { // should I include new lines?
                                InputMismatchException notDim = new InputMismatchException(
                                        "Row and Column have already been provided on the first line of the file. The extra integer: "
                                                + "'" + dimToken[2] + "'" + " should not be included.");
                                System.out.println(file + "");
                                System.out.println(notDim);
                                System.out.println("INVALID");
                                System.out.println();
                            } else {
                                // Catches if the variables on the first line are of type integer
                                int trueRow = 0;
                                int trueCol = 0;
                                try {
                                    trueRow = Integer.parseInt(trueRowStr);
                                    trueCol = Integer.parseInt(trueColStr);
                                    // Catches if a token is not a number in the file
                                    int rowCount = 0;
                                    int colCount = 0;
                                    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
                                        String line = fileScan.nextLine().trim();
                                        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                                            rowCount++;// Counts actual number of rows
                                        }
                                        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
                                        while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
                                            String token = lineScan.next().trim(); // should I include trim?
                                            double intToken = Double.parseDouble(token);
                                            colCount++;// Counts actual number of columns, divide by rowCount to get actual
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // Checks to see if row and column matches the actual number of rows and columns
                                    double roundToRealRowCount = (rowCount / 1.0); // This is to account for rounding of
                                                                                    // integer
                                    double roundToRealColCount = (colCount / roundToRealRowCount);// if row or column is not
                                                                                                    // divided evenly
                                    if (rowCount != trueRow) {
                                        InputMismatchException notRow = new InputMismatchException(
                                                "Number of rows decleration: " + "'" + trueRow + "'"
                                                        + " on first line does not match the actual number of rows in file.");
                                        System.out.println(file + "");
                                        System.out.println(notRow);
                                        System.out.println("INVALID");
                                        System.out.println();
                                    } else if (roundToRealColCount != trueCol) {

                                        InputMismatchException notCol = new InputMismatchException(
                                                "Number of columns decleration: " + "'" + trueCol + "'"
                                                        + " on first line does not match the actual number of columns in file.");
                                        System.out.println(file + "");
                                        System.out.println(notCol);
                                        System.out.println("INVALID");
                                        System.out.println();
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println(file + "");
                                        System.out.println("VALID");
                                        System.out.println();
                                    }
                                } catch (NumberFormatException notNum) {
                                    NumberFormatException notDouble = new NumberFormatException(
                                            "This value in your file: " + notNum.getMessage() + " is not a number.");
                                    System.out.println(file + "");
                                    System.out.println(notDouble);
                                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                                    System.out.println();
                                    // System.out.println(file + "");
                                    // System.out.println(notNum); // Says input string is that ok? How to change?
                                    // System.out.println("INVALID");
                                    // System.out.println();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException notFound) {
                            System.out.println(file + "");
                            System.out.print(notFound);
                            System.out.println("INVALID");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(file + "");
                        FileNotFoundException noFile = new FileNotFoundException(
                                file + " (The system cannot find the file specified)");
                        System.out.println(noFile);
                        System.out.println("INVALID");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Usage: $ java FormatChecker file1 [file2 ... fileN]");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/176021/9357)

Answer (score 1):

1. Break up your code into methods, each with clear purpose and description
2. Avoid nested if-else blocks if possible
3. Use exceptions for error conditions, rather than if-else blocks
4. use one method for reporting errors, instead of repeating the code

Instead of:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    if(file.exists() && file.isFile()){
    // do a lot of work here
    } else {
    //report error
    }
}
```

You should reverse the condition and exit on error. Like this:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
{
    // Signal error and exit
}
if(!file.exists() || !(file.isFile()))
{
   // Signal error and exit
}

//Do some work
```

Or, better

```
try {
// do some work
   if(!file.exists())
   {
      throw new RuntimeException("Input file not found");
   }
}
catch(Exception x)
{
   this.reportError(x);
}
```