# Read in a file, check that it meets certain criteria

Tags: java, file, validation, csv

This was my original posting: [Check that a data file contains the expected number of rows and columns of integers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175978/check-that-a-data-file-contains-the-expected-number-of-rows-and-columns-of-integ)

I updated the code.  Still what could I improve on?

Another question I have is how come my last method fileContent() does not need any throws declaration in the method header?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormatChecker2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FormatChecker2 tester = new FormatChecker2(); // To avoid every method being static.

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Usage: $ java FormatChecker file1 [file2 ... fileN]");
        } else {
            for (String fileName : args) {
                try {
                    tester.readInTextFile(fileName);
                    System.out.println(fileName + "");
                    System.out.println("VALID");
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException notFound) {
                    System.out.println(notFound.getMessage() + "");
                    System.out.println(notFound + " (The system cannot find the file specified)");
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (NumberFormatException notInt) {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    // String printMessage = notInt.toString().replaceAll("#.*?;", ""); "#" + file +
                    // ";"
                    System.out.println(notInt);
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (InputMismatchException badContent) {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    System.out.println(badContent);
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (IllegalCharacterException delChar) {
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    System.out.println(delChar);
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void readInTextFile(String fileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalCharacterException, NumberFormatException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
            parseFile(file);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);
        }
    }

    public void parseFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalCharacterException {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        String declaredRowCol = fileScan.nextLine().trim();
        String[] dimensions = declaredRowCol.split("\\s+");
        String declaredRowStr = dimensions[0];
        String declaredColStr = dimensions[1];
        int rowCount = 0;
        int colCount = 0;
        String notAllNumbers = "";
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScan.nextLine().trim();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                rowCount++;// Counts actual number of rows
            }
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
                String token = lineScan.next().trim(); // should I include trim?
                char letterCheck = token.charAt(0);
                // Checks to make sure the content of this file includes only numbers
                if (Character.isLetter(letterCheck)) {
                    notAllNumbers = letterCheck + "";
                }
                colCount++; // Counts actual number of columns, divide by rowCount to get actual
            }
            lineScan.close();
        }
        // Checks to make sure there is not an extra integer on the first line
        if (dimensions.length > 2) {
            throw new IllegalCharacterException(
                    "Row and Column have already been provided on the first line of the file. The extra integer: "
                            + "\"" + dimensions[2] + "\"" + " should not be included.");
        } else if (!notAllNumbers.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalCharacterException(
                    "This value in your file: " + "\"" + notAllNumbers + "\"" + " is not a number.");
        } else {
            formatDimensions(dimensions, declaredRowStr, declaredColStr, rowCount, colCount);
        }
    }

    public void formatDimensions(String[] dimensions, String declaredRowStr, String declaredColStr, int rowCount,
            int colCount) throws IllegalCharacterException, NumberFormatException, FileNotFoundException {

        int declaredRow = 0;
        int declaredCol = 0;
        // Catches if the variables on the first line are of type integer
        try {
            declaredRow = Integer.parseInt(declaredRowStr);
            declaredCol = Integer.parseInt(declaredColStr);
            fileContent(declaredRow, declaredCol, rowCount, colCount);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("This value on the first line of your file:"
                    + e.getMessage().substring(17, e.getMessage().length()) + " is not of type integer.");
        }
    }

    public void fileContent(int declaredRow, int declaredCol, int rowCount, int colCount)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalCharacterException {

        // Checks to see if row and column matches the actual number of rows and columns
        double roundToRealRowCount = (rowCount / 1.0); // This is to account for rounding of
                                                        // integer
        double roundToRealColCount = (colCount / roundToRealRowCount);// if row or column is not
                                                                        // divided evenly

        if (rowCount != declaredRow) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("Number of rows declaration: " + "'" + declaredRow + "'"
                    + " on first line does not match the actual number of rows in file.");
        } else if (roundToRealColCount != declaredCol) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("Number of columns declaration: " + "'" + declaredCol + "'"
                    + " on first line does not match the actual number of columns in file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...but I see fileContent method does have `throws` clause ....

Comment: all the printing inside the catch clauses look very similar. should be put in a method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split method in the String class to count the columns.

```
String[] columns = line.split(SEPARATOR);
int colCount = columns.length.
```